# How to include category chooser widget in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I created a module that has an admin form with select box to choose the type of linking. The user can choose the types like product, category, and brand. Whether type is category then a modal showing all categories and user can choose a category and the category id will save into a field. I don't know how to include category chooser in admin form anyone can help me enter image description here?

**Category chooser button:**

[image: Category chooser button]

**Category chooser modal:**

[image: Category chooser modal]